# Extracting values inside double quotes from a text file

Tags: c

I'm trying to extract only the values which are inside double quotes and put them in a 2d array to sort them afterwards.

My file is like this:

```
{“timestamp1”: “value1”, “timestamp2”: “value2”, … , “timestampN”: “valueN”}

{“timestamp1”: “value1”, “timestamp2”: “value2”, … , “timestampN”: “valueN”}

{“timestamp1”: “value1”, “timestamp2”: “value2”, … , “timestampN”: “valueN”}
```

Im trying to extract (timestamp1,value1),(timestamp2,value2), e.t.c.
Each brace {} is a different day with multiple timestamps and values. I'm reading the file normally but I cannot extract the timestamps and values.

Comment: Are the timestamps and the values strings, integers, or floats?

Comment: `strtok` is probably what you want.

Comment: {"2014-02-13T06:20:00": "3.0", "2014-02-13T13:50:00": "7.0"}
For example this is the first day.Timestamp is string,and value is float.
I tried strtok but i believe im doing something very wrong.

Comment: Are you going to convert them to something else, or just leave them strings?

Comment: From your example, it looks like you have a json file.

Unless you would like to keep your C pure without added libaries, i'd recommend using something like [`json-c`](https://github.com/json-c/json-c) to parse your input and use it however you'd like.

Comment: For now i will leave the timestamps as string,and the values as float to make 4 types of sorting.Its a txt file not a json one if thats what your asking.I prefer to keep my C clean but i will look up the link you send thanks.

Comment: You seem to have "smart quotes" are you working on an Apple?

Comment: You could break up the lines and feed every line into a function that specializes on parsing said json then.

Comment: The file was made from my professor probably he is on mac.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* data
{"timestamp1": "value1", "timestamp2": "value2", "timestampN": "valueN"}
{"timestamp1": "value1", "timestamp2": "value2", "timestampN": "valueN"}
{"timestamp1": "value1", "timestamp2": "value2", "timestampN": "valueN"}
*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int ch;

while(1) {
        ch = getc(stdin);
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        switch (ch) {
        case '{' : ch = '('; break;
        case '}' : ch = ')'; break;
        case '"' : continue;
        default: break;
                }
        if (ch == ',') putc(')' ,stdout);
        if (ch == ':' ) putc(',',stdout);
        else putc(ch,stdout);
        if (ch == ',') putc('(' ,stdout);
        }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**
You're looking for the`scanf()` family of functions which are well documented (in this case likely `sscanf()` to string scan a buffer line. To deal with the double quotes you'll need to escape them with a backslash `\"` when you want to treat them as string literals.

To loop this use the `%n` specifier when using `sscanf()` to advanced through your string by keeping track of number of bytes read.

You could also consider using `strtok()` string tokeniser to split your lines into sub-strings.

**Long Answer:**

The overall high level approach I'd take is the following:

1. Define your memory. If you don't know how much pass through the file once and work out how many lines you have and how many values `N` you have on each line. Use something like `fgets()`. You'll be allocating, likely, some kind of 2D array either statically or dynamically.
2. Loop through your file one line (day) at a time generating a new `line` string which has braces removed. Note there are subtleties here in making sure you end with a null byte `\0` and potentially dealing with newlines `\n` and carriage returns `\r` properly. In each loop call `scanf()`.

I'm going to assume your timestamps are `ints` and your `values as doubles` - modify types as appropriate. If you don't know the type of values you're reading in start by reading them all as strings and then later converting to `float` or `integer` or whatever other type your require through`atof()` and `atoi()` families of functions.

You're code should look something like this toy example. Passing files and building the memory structures to hold them properly is not trivial in C for real examples.

```
//Declare 2D arrays
int timestamps[NUM_DAYS][N]; 
double values[NUM_DAYS][N]; 
char *line;
int num_vals = 0; 
int offset = 0; 

/* Some code which fills your line buffer from file an removes braces */

//Each call of sscanf should return 2 if successful. Below code will poplate a single day/row of data. Put a parent loop above to loop through number of rows. 
while (sscanf(line, "\"%d\": \"%f\",%n" ,&timestamps[day][num_vals], &values[day][num_vals], &offset) == 2){
    num_vals++; 
    line+=offset; 
}
```

Comment: Hello everyone is been 1 week since i posted this.I tried for hours and hours and still can get through it.I tried Rohan's answer but somewhere im failing at it.If anyone has time and can give me more help with code i will be glad thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you have tried. We can then point out issue/errors.